# Work with CustomViewController as top bar of views

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

I have made a class with xib file called TopHeaderViewController now i use another class named iShared that as a Shared instance method. 
In iShared i have a @property called topHeader now when i first call sharedInstance on iShared i call: topHeader = [[TopHeaderViewController alloc]init]; and every time i navigate through another viewController i put this view on the top of the view controller. 
The view appear correctly but the button doesn't fire event.

Code for viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
ishared = [iShared sharedInstance];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
UIView *v = [ishared initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, headerView.frame.size.height)];

[headerView addSubview:v];

}
```

Code for iShared:

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];

topHeaderVC = [[TopHeaderViewController alloc]init];

}
```

code for TopHeaderViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
mainMenuController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenuController"];
mainMenuController.superViewController = superViewController;
mainMenuController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, mainMenuController.view.frame.size.width, mainMenuController.view.frame.size.height);
[topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sfondo_nero_sfumato"]]];
[topView setFrame:CGRectMake(topView.frame.origin.x , topView.frame.origin.y, superViewController.view.frame.size.width, topView.frame.size.height)];
ishared = [iShared sharedInstance];
[self aggiornaTicketNotificationValue_betCoupon:ishared.betCoupon];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                             name:NOTIFICATION_AGGIORNA_TOPHEADER_COUPON_LABEL
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                             name:NOTIFICATION_AGGIORNA_TOPHEADER_ACCOUNT_DETAIL
                                           object:nil];
}
- (IBAction)mnClick:(id)sender {
iShared *ishared = [iShared sharedInstance];
if (![ishared menuAperto]){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay: 0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         mainMenuController.view.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [superViewController.view addSubview:mainMenuController.view];
    ishared.menuAperto = true;
}else{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay: 0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         mainMenuController.view.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [mainMenuController.view removeFromSuperview];

    ishared.menuAperto = false;
}

}
```

anyone knows why i'm getting this trouble to get my button work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that what you're doing is totally illegal and incoherent. You cannot just shove a view controller's view into your interface. View controllers have a structural hierarchy that parallels their views, and you are completely disregarding that. The result is that you end up with the view without the view controller.

So what *should* you do? Well, we can look at it from two directions. One is that you might want to know how to insert a view controller's view *correctly* into your interface. The answer is that you have to make that view controller a *child* of your current view controller, and do a careful "custom container controller" dance, [as I describe here](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers).

However, I would suggest that that is *not* what you want to do here. The fact is, it seems to me, that your situation is just an inappropriate use of a view controller. You don't need a view controller here at all. You are just using the view controller in effect to go "dumpster diving" to retrieve the view designed the *xib* file. But you do not need a view controller to do that! You can do everything you want to do here just using a *xib* file and view subclasses that embody the desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have made a custom UIVIew with menu button bar.
But now i got the "not in view hierarchy error" when try to present other controllers from menu

Comment: @MirkoFogazzi If you have a new problem, ask a new question!